# How to split a single column values into two columns without null values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below is the orginal table looks like.

```
| Catid| Name  |
| ---- | ----  |
|1     | ramesh|
|1     | suresh|
|1     | mahesh|
|2     | rahul |
|2     | rajesh|
```

I need the o/p as

```
|catname1 | catname2|
| ----    | ----    |
|ramesh   | rahul   |
|suresh   | rajesh  |
|mahesh   |         |
```

I tried the below query but this produce null values

```
select (case when s1.catid=1 then s1.name end) as cat1name,
       (case when s1.catid=2 then s1.name end) as cat2name
from deemucty.sample12 as s1
```

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: @TanjimRahman: the question is tagged with `postgresql`

Comment: is the `Catid` always 1 or 2

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't supply somthing to order by the names, I've ordered them alphabetically.

```
select      min (case catid when 1 then name end)  as catname1
           ,min (case catid when 2 then name end)  as catname2

from       (select      row_number () over (partition by catid order by name)  as rn
                       ,catid
                       ,name

            from        deemucty.sample12
            ) t

group by    rn

order by    rn
;
```

Comment: We can just order by `catid` itself in `row_number ()`

Comment: @Nikhil, that would be meaningless since we partition by catid

Comment: @Abinesh, did that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by doing a full outer join between all names from one catid with all names from the other catid:

```
select t1.name as catname1, 
       t2.name as catname2
from (
  select name, row_number() over (order by name) as rn
  from the_table
  where catid = 1
) t1
  full join (
    select name, row_number() over (order by name) as rn
    from the_table
    where catid = 2
  ) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Example: http://rextester.com/KJLFAR74695